# how to load high resolution image windows phone taskagent? [out of memory]

Tags: windows-phone-8, lockscreen

As we know, it is only 11.5MB memory that can be used in a Windows Phone 8 task agent. I was trying to make dynamic lock screen image in the background task agent. When I get the 480*800 image, it works fine but when I change it to 768*1280 I the exception:

> **Out of memory**

**1 pixel cast 4 K**

so

**(480*800*4)/1024/1024=1.46M**

**(768*1280*4)/1024/1024 = 3.75M**

When I tried to convert a byte[] to a BitmapImage:

```
public BitmapImage ConvertDownloadStringToStream(byte[] downloadImageBytes)
{
    if (!(downloadImageBytes.Length > 0))
        return null;

    RationImageInfo currentRationInfor = GetBitmapImageWidthByDeveiceRatio();
    BitmapImage convertBitmapImage = new BitmapImage() { DecodePixelWidth =768, DecodePixelHeight = 1280};

    using (MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream(downloadImageBytes))
    {
        convertBitmapImage.SetSource(imageStream);//out of memory        
    }          

    return convertBitmapImage;
}
```

I get the out of memory exception at `SetSource()` method. Does anyone have suggestions about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the memory adds up.

Try saving it to a file, free the variable/resource, than load it from the file using the constructor parameter.

Comment: as you see. i was tried convert byte[] to bitmap and save to local so when i excute convert step throw exception。

Answer (score 0):

just try some many times i has been fix this problem.
as you see it was only have 11M memory can be use in windows phone taskagent. i was tring to make dynamic lock screen background. my soluction is download image from sever side and save to local display it.

**why got out of memory Exception?**

**download image Byte[]=>Write to memory=>build writeableBitmap with 768*1280.**

same image memory just cast three time .

**so how to fix it ?**

when you download your image from server side. you should be save to local isolate storage immediately and clear memory useage about the image byte[]. just set the image url to lockscreen . got be work.

**download image Byte[]=>Save To local =>clear image byte memory.**

everything is fine.