# Error when setting "large" data stream as source for BitmapImage

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone, bitmapimage

I use a cache mechanism, which saves images to the isolated storage and load it the next times, especially when there's no internet connection. However, it works fine for small images, but not for "large" images which are about 200kb.

This is my code:

```
public static object ExtractFromLocalStorage(Uri imageFileUri, string imageStorageFolder)
{
    var isolatedStoragePath = GetFileNameInIsolatedStorage(imageFileUri, imageStorageFolder);

    MemoryStream dataStream;
    using (var fileStream = Storage.OpenFile(isolatedStoragePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        if (fileStream.Length > int.MaxValue)
            return null;
        dataStream = new MemoryStream((int)fileStream.Length);
        var buffer = new byte[4096];
        while (dataStream.Length < fileStream.Length)
        {
            var readCount = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(buffer.Length, (int)(fileStream.Length - dataStream.Length)));
            if (readCount <= 0)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }
            dataStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
        }
    }
    var bi = new BitmapImage();
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => bi.SetSource(dataStream));
    return bi;
}
```

Small images work fine, but I get the following exception when `bi.SetSource` is being called, when loading such 200kb+ images:
    The component cannot be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88982F50)

Is there anything I can do about it? 200kb is not too large and the file is saved fine and exists locally. I hope someone can help me since it's the last stopper for my app... :/

**EDIT (31 jan):**

I started all over again, using the KawagoeToolkit library which I extended by necessary methods for my app. It works well, but I still wonder why the above gives such a strange exception.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the image?

Comment: This is different, most are about 800x600. It are fullscreen images from Foursquare (thumbs etc work fine), e.g. this one: https://irs2.4sqi.net/img/general/original/2DMDNSQXGMVWJBUSSTA4LRVIUVQKXUBONTEBJ5CKI5VJHFRM.jpg

Comment: Is it WP7 or WP8? Is the exception happen always thrown for certain image and if so could you post that image? So far I've been unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: Have you tried setting the position on `dataStream` to 0 before using it? Are you sure it's okay to create the `BitmapImage` *not* on the `Dispatcher` thread? What are you doing with the `BitmapImage` that you're returning? (Perhaps there's a race condition between that and setting the source?) Oh, and if you can use `Stream.CopyTo`, it'll get rid of a bunch of code in the middle.

Comment: It's on WP8, occuring on 920 as well as 1520. It happens to several images, e.g. for the one linked above. I use a map with several map layers on the page, but memory should not be a problem according to the Profiler. I pass an object to a new page, the image viewer. There is a image with source binding. The binding's converter gets the local BitmapImage, if it exists (it does exist, the length of the stream is correct). I set dataStream to 0 before, it doesn't work as well. Without the dispatcher it doesn't work as well, because I navigate the page, I used dispatcher just to make sure.

Comment: Regarding getting rid of the bunch of code, `var bi = new BitmapImage(); bi.SetSource(fileStream); return bi;` between the `using` brackets would be enough, too. Though this didn't work and I tried to do the whole thing more properly.

Comment: Hi sibbl,Can you please see the following post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491566/how-to-load-high-resolution-image-windows-phone-taskagent-out-of-memory

Comment: Thanks, djfox. However, the memory is not the problem as I don't get a OutOfMemory exception. Also, I profiled the app on the Lumia 1520 (2GB) with the extended memory flag, still the app was only using about 60 MB memory. I got it working by starting all over again using the code of the KawagoeToolkit library, but I still wonder why this is not working :/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the dispatcher when you don't have to. It will introduce the closure semantics.
In your method, it does not make sense, even if you were in another synchronization context. Since there is nothing from the GUI-thread involved.

Anyway, I´ve tested your code, but with one difference - I've used StorageFile instead of IsolatedStorage. And it works perfectly.

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //622Kb: http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/1920x1080_autoletterbox/public/pia17147.jpg?itok=6jErm40V
        //2.7Mb: http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/304_lunar_transit_14-00_ut_0.jpg
        StorageFile imageFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(@"Assets\test3.jpg");
        MemoryStream mz;
        using (var z = await imageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            if (z.Length > int.MaxValue) return;
            mz = new MemoryStream((int)z.Length);
            var buffer = new byte[4096];

            while (mz.Length < z.Length)
            {
                var readCount = z.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(buffer.Length, (int)(z.Length - mz.Length)));
                if (readCount <= 0)
                {
                    throw new NotSupportedException();
                }
                mz.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
            }                
        }

        var bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(mz);
        //Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => img.Source = bmp); // if in another sync context only
        img.Source = bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I also tried loading big assets using this method, but I cache images from an API which are not in the installed location of the app. They also shouldn't be cached there, should they?